# Is Simba a politician?

Tags: movie, disney, animation

I ask because he is the King of Pride Rock.

But I do not know if Simba is a monarch, or a dictator, or a tribal chief, or two of the three, or all of the three.

Also, I do not know if it would be more appropriate to call Simba authoritarian or statist.

However, I think monarchs can only be considered politicians if they are absolute (like Louis XIV of France), not if they are constitutional (like Elizabeth II of the United Kingdom).

I must say that a dictator does not necessarily mean a "bad one", it just means a ruler that has absolute power over the organization they rule (Mustafa Kemal Atatürk of Turkey, and Lee Kuan Yew of Singapore are good examples of benevolent dictators).

Comment: This seems very opinion-based. Clearly (King) Simba has relationships with other tribes (notably Zira's outsiders) and other nations (notably the hyenas) but I'm not sure you'd describe a [tribal chieftain](https://www.britannica.com/topic/chief-political-leader) as a *politician*, even if we had a single cohesive definition of the term 'politician' (which we don't).

Comment: @mammifereviolet4694  There is a very wide spectrum of power between a totally absolute monarch (if such a position could ever exist) and a totally powerless ceremonial monarch. Implying that all monarchs are either absolutely absolute or absolutely constituional with nothing in between is grossly inaccurate.  From 1832 to 1906 the Fundimental Laws of the Russian Empire said the Emperor was an absolute monarch.  So it is possible for a constituion to say that the monarch is an absolute monarch and for a monarch to be both absolute and constitutional.

Comment: It sounds like you're really asking about the definition of the term "politician." Once you've decided on a clear definition of the term, it won't be tough to figure out whether or not Simba fits it. If you haven't decided on it, then the question is about the definition of a word, and is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simba is a politician in the sense that he is an absolute king, there is not any constitution or norm that surpass the will of the king so by your answer he is a politician.

King have absolute power but is rare to call a king a dictator, a king rule because some natural law that dictates the natural order but a dictator is some guy who is in power.

A tribal chief rule a tribe, something small in size and family. The pride lands have all kind of animals and is really vast, from the Sahara to the Kilimanjaro so Simba is a King based on real politic.

Also The Lion King is based in Hamlet, a work with an absolute king so more proof to the argument that Simba is an absolute king

Comment: This seems a very opinion-based answer to an opinion-based question that's well on its way to closure.